# log4j timestamps are inconsistent and growing worse

Tags: log4j, timestamp, tcserver

I'm seeing gradually diverging timestamp values in the log output of log4j from tcserver on my RHEL 5.5 system. The system clock says it is 12:28:11, yet the logs range as far as an hour earlier. This is a VM, with no ntp daemon but with vmware-tools installed. None of the other VMs on this vhost running the same application exhibit this behavior.

Does anyone have an idea as to what could cause this?

1. This is a multithreaded application
2. Yesterday's timestamps were off by only a second.

[14/08/14 12:28:11:011 EDT] TRACE client.AcManager:404 - Normalized URL: rest/null

[14/08/14 11:42:44:044 EDT] TRACE filter.HttpRequestFilter:159

[14/08/14 12:28:11:011 EDT] TRACE client.AcManager:393 - Checking local authentication

[14/08/14 11:42:44:044 EDT] TRACE client.AcManager:404 - Normalized URL: rest/null

[14/08/14 12:28:11:011 EDT] TRACE client.AcManager:419 - The url requires local 
authentication

[14/08/14 11:42:44:044 EDT] TRACE lib.ConnectionPool:235 - Released DB statement.

[14/08/14 11:42:44:044 EDT] TRACE client.AcManager:419 - The url requires local authentication

[14/08/14 11:42:44:044 EDT] TRACE lib.ConnectionPool:235 - Released DB statement.

[14/08/14 11:42:44:044 EDT] TRACE client.AcManager:404 - Normalized URL: rest/null

[14/08/14 12:28:11:011 EDT] TRACE client.AcManager:419 - The url requires local authentication

[14/08/14 11:42:44:044 EDT] TRACE lib.ConnectionPool:235 - Released DB statement.

[14/08/14 12:28:11:011 EDT] TRACE lib.ConnectionPool:209 - Released DB connection.

[14/08/14 11:42:44:044 EDT] TRACE lib.ConnectionPool:235 - Released DB statement.

[14/08/14 11:38:57:057 EDT] TRACE client.AcManager:219 - Normalized URL: rest/info

[14/08/14 12:28:11:011 EDT] TRACE client.AcManager:235 - Using local auth data

[14/08/14 12:28:11:011 EDT] TRACE client.AcManager:268 - The url matches allow pattern: .*

[14/08/14 11:38:57:057 EDT] TRACE client.AcManager:304 - Normalized URL: rest/info

[14/08/14 11:34:30:030 EDT] TRACE lib.ConnectionPool:144 - Acquired DB statement.

[14/08/14 11:34:30:030 EDT]  INFO managed.PerfService:56 - Executing a call to metricsdata

[14/08/14 11:34:30:030 EDT] TRACE lib.ConnectionPool:144 - Acquired DB statement.

[14/08/14 11:34:30:030 EDT]  INFO managed.XbrcService:406 - Executing a call to status

[14/08/14 11:34:30:030 EDT]  INFO managed.Service:56 - Executing a call to metricsdata

[14/08/14 11:34:30:030 EDT]  INFO managed.Service:406 - Executing a call to locationinfo

[14/08/14 11:34:30:030 EDT] TRACE client.AcManager:293 - Checking if url is protected

[14/08/14 12:31:26:026 EDT] TRACE filter.RequestFilter:159 - Filter SID = 2E549D291

[14/08/14 12:31:26:026 EDT] TRACE managed.System:63 - Trying to get status

[14/08/14 12:31:26:026 EDT] TRACE client.AcManager:368 - Normalized URL: rest/config

[14/08/14 12:41:23:023 EDT] TRACE client.AcManager:293 - Checking if url is protected

[14/08/14 12:31:26:026 EDT]  INFO server.HealthConsumer:312 - Failed to resolve name

Comment: Do you have a high serverload? I believe I once saw something similar when a lot of users were doing things simultaneously?